How to enable cross link (natbib tags) using Pandoc
My codes are follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[sectionbib,authoryear,sort]{natbib}%

\RequirePackage[bookmarks=false,colorlinks=false,breaklinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,hidelinks,%
]{hyperref}%

\begin{document}

\title{Article title}

\author{Author 1, Author2}

\date{}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
The emergence of complex optimization problems in various fields of science and engineering has made it challenging to find the optimal solution promptly using traditional numerical optimization methods, such as integer programming, mathematical programming, Newtonian, and quasi-Newtonian methods \citep{yang2020nature}.

The shaded area represents the range of fluctuations observed in the fitness decreasing curve over the 10 trials. The statistical results of the convergence rate, standard deviation, and MSE for different optimization algorithms are presented in Table \ref{table:1}.

\begin{table*}
\caption{The results of four algorithms in different test functions.\label{table:1}}{%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lllllll@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\hline     
Function & Algorithm & Optimum  &  Worst & Convergence rate  & Standard deviation & MSE \\ 
\hline  
{ACKLEY} & SOEA & 0 & 0 & 15.3\%  & 0& 0 \\
\end{tabular*}}{}
\end{table*}

\begin{thebibliography}{34}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{DOI:\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{DOI:\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup
  \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[{Yang(2020)}]{yang2020nature}
Yang  XS (2020) Nature-inspired optimization algorithms: Challenges and open
  problems.
\newblock \emph{Journal of Computational Science} 46:\break 101104.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

I'm converting to HTML format using Pandoc by using the command:
pandoc trial.tex --standalone --filter pandoc-crossref --natbib --mathjax --output trial.html

It converted, but cross links were not coming properly as per TeX output:

Please advise what I did wrong, kindly note that I'm new to Pandoc
I'm using Windows10
